# Prevent create and delete on a One2many tree view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have this `One2many` field displayed as a tree view, and I want to prevent creation and deletion of rows conditionally, but also leave the existing rows editable, so `readonly` wont work for me, as it hide the the `add an item` button and `trash` icon but make the field non editable.

I tried `attrs="{'create': [('order_type', '!=', 'renewal)]}"` on the tree tag, same for delete, but it did not work.

is it possible to do that form xml, without having to write some JS code ?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handle this using 2 fields. In your model add another reference to the same records:

```
editable_lines_ids = fields.One2many(
    'reference.to.model',
    'field_id'
)
no_editable_lines_ids = fields.One2many(
    'reference.to.model',
    'field_id'
)
```

Then, in the view add the two fields but with conditionally visibility:

```html
<field
    name="editable_lines_ids"
    mode="tree"
    attrs="{'invisible': [('order_type', '!=', 'renewal)]}">
    <tree
      string="Lines"
      create="1"
      editable="bottom"
      delete="1">
        <field name="example_field"/>
    </tree>
</field>
<field
    name="no_editable_lines_ids"
    mode="tree"
    attrs="{'invisible': [('order_type', '=', 'renewal)]}">
    <tree
      string="Lines"
      create="0"
      editable="bottom"
      delete="0">
        <field name="example_field"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```